# how to fix this slider with react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a carousel for my portfolio, but whenever I try to do it using react I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')". I believe this error is happening because my code is not using a react property, but my main suspicion is that the carousel container is not loading when starting the page, is there any way to correct this error? I tried using useEffect but I couldn't fix it.

```
const App2 = () => {
    const containerImgCurriculo: any = document.getElementById("containerImgCurriculo")

    let dermarcadorPosiSlider = 550
    let imgSelecionada = 1

    function moverEsquerda() {
        
        dermarcadorPosiSlider += 500
        imgSelecionada -= 1

        if (dermarcadorPosiSlider > 550) {
            dermarcadorPosiSlider = -3950
            containerImgCurriculo.style.marginLeft = dermarcadorPosiSlider + "px"
            containerImgCurriculo.style.transition = "1s"
            console.log(dermarcadorPosiSlider, imgSelecionada)
        } else {
            containerImgCurriculo.style.marginLeft = dermarcadorPosiSlider + "px"
            containerImgCurriculo.style.transition = "1s"
            console.log(dermarcadorPosiSlider, imgSelecionada)
        }
    }

    function moverDireita() {
        
        dermarcadorPosiSlider -= 500
        imgSelecionada += 1

        if (dermarcadorPosiSlider < -3950) {
            dermarcadorPosiSlider = 550
            containerImgCurriculo.style.marginLeft = dermarcadorPosiSlider + "px"
            containerImgCurriculo.style.transition = "1s"
            console.log(dermarcadorPosiSlider, imgSelecionada)
        } else {
            containerImgCurriculo.style.marginLeft = dermarcadorPosiSlider + "px"
            containerImgCurriculo.style.transition = "1s"
            console.log(dermarcadorPosiSlider, imgSelecionada)
        }

    }

    return (
        <>
            

                    <div>


                        <div id="containerImgCurriculo">
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoHTML} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoJavaScript} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoCss} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoTypeScript} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoReact} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoPython} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoGit} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoMySql} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoVite} /></div>
                            <div ><ImgCurriculo imgImgCurriculo={logoOffice} /></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <div className="" onClick={moverEsquerda}>
                                <img src={seta} alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="" onClick={moverDireita}>
                                <img src={seta} alt=""  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App2
```

I tried using useState, but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this line inside the function you are using it in:

```
const containerImgCurriculo: any = document.getElementById("containerImgCurriculo")
```

Or either use `useRef` hook.

You are getting element from the document and saving it in a variable, but the document is not made yet. After the `<App2 />` component returns, only then you can get elements from document. If you do `console.log(containerImgCurriculo)` it will log `null`. Put the line in both `moverEsquerda` and `moverDireita` functions.

It is better to use `useRef` hook tho.

[Click here to learn about useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)